# Should project analysis documents be packaged along with software?

Tags: licensing, documentation

Analysis documents can be useful to see how a project has been designed from a more abstract point of view.

However, would there be any potential downsides on packaging these along with some software on, say, GitHub?

In other words, would there be any valid reason for keeping these separate and hosted on a personal website or on SlideShare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often just a matter of manageability. A lot of developers like to keep their source control "lean and mean", which only the relevant project files there, and leave the "fluff" pieces, such as guides, documentation and analysis documents to be hosted elsewhere.

Moreover, it's important to remember that such analysis can be performed by third parties who aren't part of the project's community and have no interest in committing their work to the source tree.

Comment: Interesting what you say about leaving the "fluff" out. So perhaps the project analysis documents could be on a separate Github if a person is interested in releasing them?